# sudo does not recognize new group

Tags: centos, sudo, group, scl

Why won't `sudo` recognize my group, in a fresh login after using `groupadd`?

Our DigitalOcean CentOS comes with a borked `sudo` implementation.  It's the following script, note well line #2:

```
$ nl $(which sudo) 
     1  #! /bin/sh
     2  # TODO: parse & pass-through sudo options from $@
     3  sudo_options="-E"

     4  for arg in "$@"
     5  do
     6     case "$arg" in
     7      *\'*)
     8        arg= ;;
     9     esac
    10     cmd_options="$cmd_options '$arg'" 
    11  done
    12  exec /usr/bin/sudo $sudo_options \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH=$PATH \
scl enable devtoolset-7 "$cmd_options"
```

Having fixed that script to pass through `sudo` options, I'm unable to invoke an executable as a group.  My script ends with:

```
exec /usr/bin/sudo -g foo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[...] /lib PATH=[...] \
scl enable devtoolset-7 install -o jim -g foo -m 2755 [files...]
sudo: unknown group: 'foo'
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

But the group is defined:

```
$ grep foo /etc/group
foo:x:1004:
```

and I am in the group:

```
$ id
uid=1003(jim) gid=1003(jim) groups=1003(jim),10(wheel),1004(foo) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

In case it matters:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

Comment: The official tutorials shown here  - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos show a different method for adding groups.

Comment: No, that tutorial doesn't show how to add a group.  It describes how to configure sudo.  I'm in the wheel group, and sudo is configured to let wheel do anything.  If groupadd doesn't add groups, what does?

Comment: My mistake, it shows the addition of adding a user to a existing group.